# Mongosh(shell) assign unique increasing number to every document

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

For the purpose of a product number, how can I assign an integer counting upwards starting with 001 to every document using **mongo-shell**?

As a results every document should have a unique "number" field.
My starting point is of course using `updateMany()`.

```sh
db.items.updateMany({}, {$set: {number: [xxx]}})
```

Comment: When a new document is created, product numbers from deleted documents should be re-assigned without others being changed of course.

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion with ongoing inserts getting the next highest number?    And clarification:  when docs are deleted, then those numbers go back to the available pool...?

Comment: Yes, this is a one-time job for existing documents. Every newly created document will be assigned the lowest available number from the available pool. Whereas the pool is basicly infinite.

Comment: Forgot to ask:  do you require reusing numbers from the pool esp. if the pool is infinite?   Why not monotonically increasing bit pattern?

Comment: Don't even ask. Customers choice. There basically has the be a reuse or at least a fake reuse. I've now writting a short node script to do this. I just thought there would be a handy mongosh version :) Thank you! If you have recommendations in how to find the lowest available number which is not assigned be free.